# Организация сети для Kerio Control

Tags: firewall

День добрый,

Мне нужно знать интернет трафик каждого пользователя сети и список посещаемых сайтов, попалась под руку программу которая может вести такую статистку Kerio Control. Кто имел дело с Kerio Control подскажите имеет ли значение организация сети. В  компании все компы организованы в сеть через роутер, через него же и выход в интернет. kerio будет работать только если пустить всю сеть через один шлюз (сервера) или можно поставить его на каждую машину и сливать показания на один комп!

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте его шлюзом сразу за роутером, и все компы через него. Авторизация либо в браузере либо из AD (можно и статияеские IP каждому пользователю прописать, но заводить пользователей тоже как то надо).

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!